# Django channels daphne returns 200 status code

Tags: django, nginx, django-channels

I have setup a Django application with Nginx + uwsgi. The application also uses django-channels with redis. When deploying the setup in an individual machine, everything works fine.

But when I tried to setup the app in 2 instances and setup a common load balancer to coordinate the requests, the request get properly routed to the daphne process and I can see the logs. But the status code returned from the daphne process is 200 instead of 101.

Load balancer nginx conf:

```
upstream webservers {
    server 10.1.1.2;
    server 10.1.1.3;
}


server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://webservers;
    }
}
```

Versions used:

```
daphne==2.2.4
channels==2.1.6
channels-redis==2.3.2
```

All the routing works fine and there are no errors, but just that the status code returned is 200 instead of 101.

Comment: So are you using it for http or websocket? do the consumers work as expected?

Comment: I am using it for websocket. That's why I am surprised I get a 200 status code

Comment: Are your consumers working?

Comment: @Ken4scholars Yes they are working. This problem does not happen when I try locally, or without the nginx load balancer

Comment: Aren't you overthinking things? websocket requests start with a HTTP request and handshake after which a change of protocol is initiated. Getting a 200 in the first request might actually be an expected behaviour. Moreover, as you said, your consumers are working correctly. You may be stuck on solving a non-existing problem

Comment: @Ken4scholars The browser tries to initiate a socket connection and throws an error when it gets 200 as response. And the problem here is that websockets are not supposed to get 200

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add following headers, hope that this will help:

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://webservers;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
   }
}
```

Full [official instruction](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html#nginx-supervisor-ubuntu) about how to setup Django Channels + Nginx [can be found here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html#nginx-supervisor-ubuntu)

Comment: Yes that works. Thanks. I had added it in the nginx where the app was, but not in the load balancer.

Comment: Is it possible for you to give a small brief on what upgrade does and why it is important here?